# Checking the convergence of various series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to find the convergence of 3 series, I don't know if the procedure I used is correct.

- $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cos(1/n) $$I had no idea how to proceed with this excercise
- $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2^n +4^n)/(2e)^n ∼ \sum_{n=1}^\infty = 4^n / e^n  = (4/e)^n$$ I used comparision test, so $4/e > 1$ so the series diverges
- When $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+(1/n^\frac{x}{2}) ∼\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^\frac{x}{2} $$ The series converges if $x/2 > 1, x>2$
- When $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{3nx}$$  $\sqrt[n]{e^{3nx}} = e^{3x} = (e^3)^x$ I used te root test so the series converges if $e^3 \leq t$ for $t\in (0,1)$, which is not true so the series diverges.

Comment: You probably shouldn't ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: You mean it is better that I ask a question for each exercise?

Comment: Yes.  And probably not all at once.  Ask a question and learn from it, and maybe the next question won't be necessary.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations.

- What is the following limit? $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|(-1)^n \cos
     \frac1n\right| $$
- Note that $$ \frac{2^n +4^n}{(2e)^n}=\frac{1   
     +2^n}{e^n}=\frac{1}{e^n}+\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n. $$
- For which values of $x$ do we have the following inequality? $$ |e^{3x}|<1.$$

Comment: 1) I guess the limit is equal to +1 or -1 , 2) It was that simple!  3) log 1 < 3x so x>0, is it correct?

Comment: That means that it diverges? Can you please tell me which exercises are wrong?

Comment: First series diverges since its general term does *not* tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. The second series is convergent, as a sum of two convergents series. The third series, your answer is almost fine: as $n \to \infty$, $\log\left(1+\frac1{n^{x/2}}\right) \sim \frac1{n^{x/2}}$ . The last series converges iff $x<0$.

Comment: One last thing, why 1/e^n  and (2/e)^n coverges

Comment: If $|q[<1$, then the geometric series $\sum q^n$ converges. Note that $1/e^n=(1/e)^n$, $e=2.718\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ElBryan You are very welcome!

Comment: Can I ask you again something? why we have to use this inequality |e^3x|<1. to find if the series converges?